# Capture/receive IR signals in an Android application?

Tags: infrared

Is it possible to get the HEX code of remote control from an application and a smartphone that has a infrared transmitter ? (Samsung S4)

Comment: no answer to my question?

Answer (score 0):

Android SDK, starting from 19, introduced a function for transmitting infrared signals only. so the answer is **No**.

But it's possible to do that if the manufacturer has a public API for doing that. which requires the IR module to be both transmitter and receiver and the OS driver being able to receive the data, etc.

Answer (score -3):

Sorry! I don't know about that. But you can use an Arduino board with IR receiver to capture and decode the IR signal and a Bluetooth module to send it to your device.